# How to create a Search in SuiteScript 2.0 version

Tags: javascript, json, search, netsuite, suitescript

I want to create an search for the record using **"SuitScript 2.0 version"** . I know that i can achieve it using **"SuiteScript 1.0"** using nlapiSearchRecord() api using filters and conditions but i want do this with SuitScript 2.0 version.
To this in "SuiteScript 2.0 " the  **"N/search Module"** have to be used but not getting how to did the search in 2.0 in equivalent to suitscript 1.0 version.

Could any one give an example for  the search in SuiteScript 2.0 version.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are correct that you will use `N/search`. It uses an analogous API to the 1.0 API of `nlapiCreateSearch`.

You will use `search.create` to build out your search object or `search.load` to load a saved search. Then you will invoke `run` on the resulting search object. Finally, you can process the results in two ways:

1. Use the `each` method and a callback
2. Use the `getRange` method to get a specific number of results

In the example below, I've imported `N/search` into my module as `s` and shown the usage of the `each` method.

```js
function findCustomers() {
    // Create and run search
    s.create({
        "type": "customer",
        "filters": [
            ['isinactive', s.Operator.IS, 'F'], 'and',
            ['company', s.Operator.NONEOF, ['123','456']
        ],
        "columns": ['email', 'firstname', 'lastname']
    }).run().each(processCustomer);
}

function processCustomer(result) {
    // do something with Customer search result
    // returns a boolean; true to continue iterating, false to stop
    return true;
}
```

Comment: https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43702/kw/N%2Fsearch

Comment: Does the column names in the filters/columns relate to any of Records Browser, Schema Browser or Connect Browser or how would you identify what to use there?

Comment: Column names come from the Search Columns section of the record type in the Records Browser.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh, can I get All columns in search result by passing an empty array to search.columns as I dont know all the columns name, or any other way to get fields of search type that is shown in "Search Columns" section of Record Browser using suite script 2.0 - thanks

Comment: No, you have to explicitly specify columns. If you want all the fields on a record, you have to load the record instead.

Comment: @erictgrubaugh could you help me on this question ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73793473/suitescript-unable-to-search-inventorydetails-subrecord-from-saved-search-data