# Netsuite - REST API - Making query with Token Based Authentication (TBA) - (in Python)

Tags: rest, web-services, oauth, netsuite

This is a follow up to the successful call using Netsuite Token Based Authentication (TBA) REST webservice,

I would like to get some guidance on how to perform a query.

I am supposed to read records like this (please see screenshot)

[image]

- how can I perform a specifc query (by table for a list of records and also specific record) ?

https://gist.github.com/axilaris/4386c3537d04737d3775c156562b7545 <-- here is the python code for the TBA that has worked successful. I would like to know how to construct the next step on how to perform the query and read specific record (as shown in the screenshot).

This is a custom record with an ID like this customrecord1589

Comment: Is this a custom record that you are trying to access?

Comment: yes, it has a custom ID like this customrecord1589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query a specific record: You're going to need to create/ deploy a RESTlet in Netsuite similar to the following:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 */
define([
    "N/log",
    "N/search",
], function (log, search) {
    
    function post(context) {
        return JSON.stringify(getCustomRecords(context));
    }

    function getCustomRecords(context) {
        log.debug('POST Context', context);
        return search.lookupFields({
            //Change CUSTOM_RECORD to the type of custom record you are querying
            type: search.Type.CUSTOM_RECORD + '1589',
            id: context.id,
            columns: context.fields,
        });
    }

    return {
        post: post,
    };
});
```

In your Python Script: Make sure you change the URL of the request to the deployment URL of this new RESTlet. Also, make sure to pass any parameters you need (like 'id' or 'fields' in my example) in your POST request payload. So instead of:

```
payload = {
 "name":"value",
 "foo":"bar",
 "duck":"hunt",
}
```

pass

```
payload = {
 "id":"9999999",
 "fields": ["custrecord_field1", "custrecord_field2"],
}
```

where id is the internalid of the record you want to query and the fields array are the internalids of the fields you want values from.

If this goes successfully, the result should show up as conn.text in your python script!

Comment: I'ved got error "Missing a required argument". https://gist.github.com/axilaris/1fdbfa6f2de3134c3b08b7492b0ddc81 . As per your guidance, I changed the payload fields and search.Type.MYENTRY refering to my custom record https://i.imgur.com/N3o1dO2.png

Comment: Do you have a good guide on how the syntax of the payload should be ? I would like to know how to do a list as well and read specific records from a query search

Comment: I updated my answer slightly, you need to add the internal id of the custom record onto the end of search.Type.CUSTOM_RECORD.
The other thing I see you need to do is for the payload use the internal ids of the custom record fields not the names. So something like "fields": ["id", "custrecord_xxxx"]. But you need to look up what they are for your custom record. I'm getting this from the 'N/search' module examples in the Netsuite help section.

Comment: thanks it worked! https://gist.github.com/axilaris/d5f7319ac39a6f6bfcf3a89570cac050. This retrieve the record by ID. Just a small favour, can you expand on how can I query by the field (custrecord3987). Thanks!

Comment: Pass that field and the value you are looking for to the RESTlet. Use search.create (instead of search.lookupFields) to create a new search where the filter is ['custrecord3987', search.Operator.EQUALTO, context.custrecord3987]. The other option is to use the query module if you are familiar with SQL and query within your RESTlet that way. Checkout the N/search or N/query sections in NetSuite's Help Center if you need more help with these modules (there are lots of examples!)

Comment: Thanks. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/70a24cd73b76f3d6b6bbd0f8681518eb here is my code that didnt work. I tried I guess from this example and input your guidance https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4345171487.html

Comment: I'ved anyway assigned the answer to you. would it be possible if you can help fix this search query as it didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I tried 2 of your example and even tried getRange() instead of each() and all failed at the same point  .run() - https://gist.github.com/axilaris/70a24cd73b76f3d6b6bbd0f8681518eb. Referred to this https://suiterep.com/2021/02/04/using-the-n-search-suitescript-module/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365828/how-to-create-a-search-in-suitescript-2-0-version/38376335. Hope you can assist further. (maybe needs to import/include something ? Thanks.