# Netsuite - REST API - How to create new Entry record with Token Based Authentication (TBA) - (in Python)

Tags: javascript, python, rest, oauth, netsuite

This is a follow up to the successful call using Netsuite Token Based Authentication (TBA) REST webservice,

I would like to get some guidance on how to create a NEW ENTRY RECORD.

Here is my custom type record entry list (please see screenshot)

[image]

https://gist.github.com/axilaris/4386c3537d04737d3775c156562b7545 <-- here is the python code for the TBA that has worked successful. I would like to know how to construct the next step on how to create a new entry.

This is a custom record with an ID like this customrecord1589

FYI - here is my other question on query [Netsuite - REST API - Making query with Token Based Authentication (TBA) - (in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69516304/netsuite-rest-api-making-query-with-token-based-authentication-tba-in-p)
But this question would be creating a new entry record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your restlet you need to use the N/record module to create a new custom record, here is what is should look similar to:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Restlet
 */
define(["N/log", "N/record"], function (log, record) {
    function post(context) {
        return JSON.stringify(createCustomRecord(context));
    }

    function createCustomRecord(context) {
        let success = true;
        try {
            let custRec = record.create({
                type: "customrecord1589",
                isDynamic: true,
            });
            //Set one or more fields here
            custRec.setValue({
                fieldId: "custrec123",
                value: context.custrec123,
            });
            custRec.save();
        } catch (e) {
            log.error("Error creating record", e);
            success = false;
        }
        return { success: success };
    }

    return {
        post: post,
    };
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723531/netsuite-rest-api-creating-record-causes-invalid-login-attempt-failure-occas <-- @Nick it appears if I call many times creating record with TBA it causes INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT. Is there a way to handle TBA and creating records separately ? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723531/netsuite-rest-api-restlet-creating-record-causes-invalid-login-attempt-fail <-- @Nick would you have any suggestion on this issue ? thanks