# Netsuite - REST API (restlet)- creating record causes INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT failure on the 2nd and more request for records

Tags: javascript, rest, oauth, netsuite, restlet

I have problems creating subsequent records with netsuite rest api using Token Based Authentication (TBA) oauth authentication. Here is my full code: https://gist.github.com/axilaris/428e63e5ff107d212fbcc07c5bdbce7a (it contains restlet, python code and the output of the python code).

The first record get created (you could see success) but the 2nd always get INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT. If I remove creating the 2nd record, it will still be successful creating each time. But if I have in a process creating 2nd or more, its always the 2nd and more will have INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT.

```
{'Authorization': b'OAuth realm="5504997_SB1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_nonce="87811756", oauth_timestamp="1635417611", oauth_token="d0c58f511e12345678c3e969e09e0ae1d967869762a354523494f0b953e9", oauth_consumer_key="117123345674ffb0b98440badb57205b3542234832cbdbabca0", oauth_body_hash="2jmj7l5rSw0yVb%2FvlWAYeqweq%2FYBwk%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256", oauth_signature="Apx76mZiSjKtF6WjLweqweqwRNV4KF1VEZAfURe8%3D"', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
Result: {"success":true}
{'X-N-OperationId': '42656b12-5874-4870-b958-631e8a298ecd', 'NS_RTIMER_COMPOSITE': '331252041:706172746E6572733031312E70726F642E6475622E6E65746C65646765722E636F6D:80', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'Pragma': 'No-Cache', 'Cache-Control': 'No-Cache', 'Expires': '0', 'Content-Length': '17', 'P3P': 'CP="CAO PSAa OUR BUS PUR"', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Date': 'Thu, 28 Oct 2021 10:40:11 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie': 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING; path=/', 'Akamai-GRN': '0.57561b3a.1635417611.239d029f'}
Result: {"error" : {"code" : "INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT", "message" : "Invalid login attempt."}}
{'WWW-Authenticate': 'OAuth realm="5008903_SB1"', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length': '84', 'P3P': 'CP="CAO PSAa OUR BUS PUR"', 'Vary': 'User-Agent', 'Date': 'Thu, 28 Oct 2021 10:40:12 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'Set-Cookie': 'NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING; path=/', 'Akamai-GRN': '0.57561b3a.1635417611.239d0735'}
```

Here is the screenshot of the Audit Trail logs
[image]

Can someone advise is authentication TBA required each time creating a record ? Is there a better way to handle this by doing TBA authentication first and then using that response (possibly a token) for creating multiple records ? Please advise as I have a platform that regularly creates records.

Comment: it sound like you have problems with the timespan or Nonce,  go to "setup->Users&Roles->View Audit login trail"  and click in  "Create saved search" then  in the result tab add "detail" Field and run the saved search,you will see  why you get   INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per SuiteAnswer [74343](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/74343)

For this example, combination of nonce + timestamp was already used by the user. Make sure to generate unique nonce to every request.

Make sure to don't send the same request twice. (If the user need do the same operation, the user must generate a new TBA header).

Comment: thanks it works! it was static somehow, we made in dynamic/unique now on each request. just an additional question, is there another way where we do the oauth TBA once and use some kind of response token for the post request ? I am checking if we can reduce some kind of load on authentication each time. Thanks

Comment: Glad it works, Have you tried The OAuth Library Consumption for Client Application (suiteAnswers 42171 https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/42171), the one for PHP is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChanahC/phpoauth/master/Oauth.php

Comment: I am using oauth2 python library. Do you know of any documentation or writeups that tell about the flow. Or have you experienced even using PHP where you authenticate once and use the authentication token for many transactions be it POST/GET etc. Thanks